# Retrieving Blender wiki pages that have been taken down

Tags: add-on, documentation

My team has been actively maintaining the user's guides to our plugins using the Blender wiki, but the pages have very recently all been taken down.  Who can I contact about at minimum retrieving the content of our pages?  (Or ideally getting the links reinstated, as we have publications with references to those links.)

I asked this community about this issue a year ago, but nobody had any better suggestions than to continue using the outdated:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/my_addon

So that's what we had been doing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the [bf-committers mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers), as there things like the current big wiki upgrade are discussed. You can find more information in the list archive.

The contents of the old wiki can be downloaded from https://download.blender.org/oldwiki/ so that people can access old data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have joined the mailing list.  However, I don't see any discussions in the last 6 months about the wiki upgrade, other than the one message from today about a "slight disruption".  So I will hope this means that our pages will be back soon!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the old wiki archive files.